# Combining two dates from two properties into one single property value in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model with two properties (End and Final).

I'm trying to set my "Final" property value with the the day and month of my "End" property value as such as the example bellow:
I'm just not sure how to accomplish this...  Any feedback would be greatly appreciated so that I could return my NewModel with the correct value.

Example:
End = 2/3/2008
Final = 1/1/2019 but I would like the value to be set as such 2/3/2019

Maybe my answer would be to create a new properties that add the value of both property?

```
var newModel = new ProgramSchedule(customerProgram.RepeatBy)
{
 End = !customerProgram.EndOn.HasValue ? (customerProgram.IsNonServiceYear ? 
 DateTime.Today.AddYears(1) : new DateTime((customerProgram.Year ?? DateTime.Today.Year), 12, 31)) : 
 customerProgram.EndOn.Value,
 Final = GetServiceYearWithDefault(),};
 return newModel;}

 public DateTime GetServiceYearWithDefault()
 {
 int defaultYear =((short?)Parameters.ParameterConfigurationService.GetParameterValue(ParameterConfiguration.GeneralParameterKeys.Year)) ?? (int)DateTime.Now.Year;
 DateTime Final = new DateTime(defaultYear, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
 return Final;
 }
```

Comment: Just pass your  `End` variable to `GetServiceYearWith Default` and set Final using `End.Month` and `End.Day` instead of `DateTime.Now.Month/Day`? This seems very obvious, what am I missing?

Comment: Your End variable seems to be globally define, so just change one line: `DateTime Final = new DateTime(defaultYear, End.Month, End.Now.Day);`

Comment: Actually it is not its not defined within the scope so I'm not really sure how to tackle this. End.Month, End.Now.Day are not within scope.

Comment: Then, just pass it to your method. `Final = GetServiceYearWithDefault(End)` and change your method signature: `public DateTime GetServiceYearWithDefault(DateTime end)`